# CouchDB on Vagrant VM (Scotch box)

Tags: vagrant, couchdb, scotchbox

I'm trying to set up CouchDB (and ultimately use PouchDB) on a Scotch Box VM.  The VM runs fine, and includes port forwarding for port 5849 by including the code below:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "scotch/box-pro"
    config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5984, host: 5984
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

The VM runs fine.  localhost:8080 will load the PHP home page, and localhost:3000 will load a node script if I have the node server running, but localhost:5984 only returns an empty response when loaded from the browser or from the host machine command line using curl `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`.

When I have used `vagrant ssh` to access the VM, I can use `curl localhost:5984` to obtain `{"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"9cabeb8f66947adabe9443594aa7f69c","version":"1.6.0","vendor":{"version":"15.10","name":"Ubuntu"}}` as expected.

Here is the guide I've been referring to:  https://pouchdb.com/guides/setup-couchdb.html

Additional info:  When I go to 192.168.33.10:5984 (instead of using the localhost port forwarding), the result is a refused connection.

Any suggestions as to what my issue might be?  I had thought it was a forwarding issue, but the ports 8080 and 3000 work fine, and going to the IP:5984 doesn't work so it makes me wonder.  I also thought maybe the service isn't running, but doing ssh on the VM and running curl seems to indicate that it is in fact running.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default CouchDB bound to a localhost address 127.0.0.1 and you need to re-bind it to 0.0.0.0 to get it accessible from outside of Vagrant box. To do that you need to change parameter [`bind_address`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.0/config/http.html#httpd/bind_address) in `[httpd]` section of `default.ini` config file or add the same as override in `local.ini` config file.

Comment: In addition, mine needed to add forwarded port in Vagrantfile as follow:
`config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5984, host: 5984`